# Telling whether or not an integral is independent of path (Complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the differential $$\frac{-y\,dx + x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}, x+iy \in \mathbb{C}-0$$ we see by an easy calculation the differential is closed on $\mathbb{C}-0$. If we integrate the differential around the unit circle, using parameterization $x=\cos\theta, y=\sin\theta$ we obtain $$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{-y\,dx + x\,dy}{x^2+y^2} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta = 2\pi.$$

Then we claim that the integral is **not independent of path**, which of course implies it is not exact on $\mathbb{C}-0$. Why is it not independent of path? Is it because it's equal to $2\pi$ or that it isn't star-shaped?

The book goes on to say that the integral is exact on $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ because it is star-shaped. Does this imply that it is also independent of path?

Comment: Do you know the definition of "independent of path"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You integrated along a path that started and ended at $1$, and you got $2\pi$.  Integrate along another path that starts and ends at $1$, namely the path that just stays at $1$, and you get $0$.  Or if you like, a path that follows the curve $|z-3/2|=1/2$.  That starts and ends at $1$, and you get $0$.

So the value of the integral depends on which route you take from $1$ to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is closed, that means that if the integral was path-independent, the result would be the same for the constant path in the point $\theta = 0$ for example. The result for this one is zero, as there is no length and the function is well defined, so your integral cannot be path-independent.